# android countdown timer is finished

Tags: android, count

In my activity i want to check if countdowntimer is finished i'll stop the activity and pass to another activity?How can i do this?
I define countdowntimer like this

```
mcountdowntimer = new CountDownTimer(25000,1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v("Log_tag", "Tick of Progress" + i + millisUntilFinished);
                i++;
                mProgressBar.setProgress(i);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {


                i++;
                mProgressBar.setProgress(i);

            }


        };
        mcountdowntimer.start();
        mProgressBar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.rgb(64,91,164)));

    }
```

Comment: Call method from onFinish() and the startActivity in that method.

Comment: Have you searched anything about `CountDownTimer` before asking  ?

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add that logic in your `onFinish()` method:

```
@Override
public void onFinish() {
     //here add the code for starting a new activity
}
```

Comment: Sure mate. Also you can remove setProgress from onFinish because it only gets called once at the end..

Comment: @AmidouFlorianTouré if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.